# The confirmation of close vote says "flag submitted"

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app

Casting a close vote from Android app 1.0.26 brings up the confirmation "Flag submitted":

[image: flag submitted]

I checked on the site that I indeed cast a close *vote* on that question, not a flag.

Although close votes are internally handled as a type of flag, from user's perspective a vote and a flag are different things. This notification made me wonder if I fat-fingered an option, or if the app converted my vote to a flag, etc.

I think the notification should say "Vote submitted" when it confirms a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.28 it'll say "Vote submitted" as suggested, thanks!

Comment: I think this fix was overdone: in 1.0.29 I get "Vote submitted" when flagging a question as Very Low Quality. That's a flag, not a vote.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills They're all votes in the backend...