# Android: "Vote to close" vs. "Flag submitted"

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app

When I use the Android app to submit a close vote, the green "pop-up bar" on the top of the screen says "flag submitted."  Instead, it *should* say something like "vote cast."

This was somewhat confusing, given that it *is* possible for lower-rep users to flag as off-topic instead of voting to close.

Below is a screencapture, with a freehand circle to highlight the problem.  (This message is displayed after *voting* to close, not submitting a flag.)

[image: Demo with freehand circle.]

Comment: Technically on our end a vote to close is a type of flag, but yeah this should say something else.

Comment: Bizarrely enough, it looks like this problem was supposedly fixed [a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226662/261498) (except I just popped into Meta.SE to write about the exact same thing, so I guess something got mixed up at some point).