# When I vote to close using the Android app, it says "Flag submitted"

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app, close-dialog, custom-close-reasons

As the title says, when I cast a close vote using the Android app, it shows a mesage saying "*Flag* submitted":

[image]

It should say "Close Vote submitted" instead, or maybe "Your vote has been recorded" like on desktop. Apparently, this [was fixed a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226662/289005), but it seems it has reappeared.

Also, the button on the dialog you get when entering a custom close reason also says "Flag" - it should say "Vote to close" or something like that instead.